# Not able to get Ram And storage information in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am getting null value in return when i am trying to get ram information and storage information in ionic.. Here is the code

```
 import { ExtendedDeviceInformation } from '@ionic-native/extended-device-information';

@IonicPage()
@Component({




 selector: 'page-location',


 templateUrl: 'location.html',

})


export class LocationPage {
 DeviceInfo={
Ram:'',
Storage:''}
constructor(private extendedDeviceInformation: ExtendedDeviceInformation,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
console.log('The Memory is: ' + this.extendedDeviceInformation.memory);
console.log('The Memory is: ' + this.extendedDeviceInformation.totalstorage);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise it's a late reply but it might be useful for others looking for an answer.
You can access the plugin through cordova directly.

```
import { ExtendedDeviceInformation } from '@ionic-native/extended-device-information';

declare var cordova: any;

@Injectable()

export class YourClass {

this.device_storage = cordova.plugins['extended-device-information'].totalstorage;

}
```